# Total differential and overestimation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y)=10-(x^2+y^2)$ at (1,1) with dx=2 and dy=3
The function value at (1,1) is 8.

Computing the change in the function by taking a first order total differential gives us $-(2xdx+2ydy)=-10$
Computing the function value at (1+dx,2+dy) gives -15, which means the change is -23.
Computing the directional derivative in the direction (2,3) gives $-2x*2/\sqrt{13} -2y*3/\sqrt{13}=-2.77$.

I understand that the first method is only an approximation (and overestimates the change in this case). But why do the second and third methods give different answers? My intuition says the third method is correct. However, does dx and dy not mean moving 2 units in the x direction and 3 units in the y direction? Starting at (1,1), that would mean computing the function value at (3,4). What am I missing?

Comment: You should have gotten exactly the same value for the directional derivative as you did with the total differential. You might want to show your calculations so that someone can point out your error instead of making everyone guess. That aside, the various types of derivatives give good approximations in a small region around a point. A displacement of $(2,3)$ is a rather large one for this function.

Comment: Have included edits as suggested by you. In calculating the directional derivative, I have converted the direction vector into a unit vector.